# How to add SQL Server 2014 instance?

Tags: sql-server, installation

I followed [this link](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server/create_multiple_instances) to install SQL Server 2014. When I clicked on "New installation or add features to an existing installation" instead of proper box, I have to choose "Browse For Folder". When I choose folder where my installation is, nothing happens. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "instead of proper box" - that is the correct choice for creating a new instance? At what point in the wizard are you browsing for a folder? Perhaps include screenshots to better describe what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link to install sql 2014 offline files
[MS SQL Server 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299)